# Does GeoServer have Public directories reachable over internet?

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to figure out whether or not there are any directories within GeoServer latest which allow me to offer image files over the internet. I am using windows server 2012. I have internet access to the endpoints (set up through a reverse proxy) which allow users to see the map services e.g servername/arcgis/services/directory/servicename/MapServer/ but as far as I know these are virtual directories and do not allow me to save images within them.

I am looking to simply find an open directory without having to set up another reverse proxy.

Comment: GeoServer is publishing images(coverages) also as WCS service and they can be downloaded with GetCoverage request.

Comment: To prevent your question being too broad please only ask about one product per question.  If you need to ask about two then I recommend always asking about the most likely to meet your requirement first.  If you then need to ask about the other, simply ask a separate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GeoServer has a special "www" directory in the data dir which is published towards the internet at "http://host/geoserver/www", but one cannot list its contents, you need to know which file to pick directly, e.g:

http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/www/styles/green.sld